# SWT: CheckboxCellEditor does not open when clicked

Tags: java, swt, jface, tablecelleditor

I have a TableViewer with data that can be edited via CheckboxCellEditor.

My code is very similar to the following example code at java2s.com: [new ComboBoxCellEditor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.eclipse.jface.viewers/newComboBoxCellEditorCompositearg0.htm).

If you run that code, create  a new person and the click in the "Age Range" cell of the entry you can see a text editor, however I would expect the combo box to be opened. 
The used CheckboxCellEditor is already defined to be *SWT.READ_ONLY* but that does not help. I also tried to replace it with an CheckboxViewerCellEditor or add *SWT.DROP_DOWN* but this all does not help.

How can I create a combo box cell editor that directly displays the list of values upon first mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can call `setActivationStyle` on the `ComboBoxCellEditor` to set what happens on activation:

```
cellEditor.setActivationStyle(ComboBoxCellEditor.DROP_DOWN_ON_KEY_ACTIVATION | ComboBoxCellEditor.DROP_DOWN_ON_MOUSE_ACTIVATION);
```